# Entering an if statement based on values in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I've made a scoring system using a list `playerScores` that contains all the scores

```
# Fake sample data    
playerScores = [5, 2, 6, 9, 0]
```

I want an if statement to run when any score in the list is equal to or less than 0

I have tried

```
if playerScores <= 0:
```

but I am told that the list is not callable

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` in combination with a generator expression to check if any list element is less than or equal to 0.

```
playerScores = [5, 2, 6, 9, 0]
if any(score <= 0 for score in playerScores):
    # At least one score is <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `playerScores` variable is a list.  Trying to compare it to `0` (or any number) won't work too well.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a <= 0
False
```

Instead use a `for` loop to check against each item in the list

```
for item in playerScores:
    if item <= 0:
        ## Do something
```

If you just want to check if there are any that are `<= 0` then just set a condition to `False`, then change it to `True` if you find one.

```
flag = False
for item in playerScores:
    if item <= 0:
        flag = True
        break

if flag:
    ## Do something
```

I have no idea why you're getting the `list not callable` error.  Using comparison with a list (as shown above) would just return `False`.  To get the error you mention you'd need something like this

```
>>> a(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a(1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here you're trying to call a list as a function `function()` instead of indexing it `list[]`

```
>>> a[1]
2
```